# Cambiar números decimales a enteros

Tags: python, diccionarios, notepad++

El caso es que tengo la siguiente línea de texto en Notepad++

```
"5113": 0.064, "6105": 0.159, "6107": 0.149, "6109": 0.127, "48213": 0.085, "6111": 0.11, "6113": 0.109, "5115": 0.062, "47077": 0.181,
```

Me gustaría cambiar todos aquellos números decimales por un 0 (entero).

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que una de las formas más simples sería utilizar la compresión. Por ejemplo:

```
xxx = {"5113": 0.064, "6105": 0.159, 
       "6107": 0.149, "6109": 0.127, 
       "48213": 0.085, "6111": 0.11, 
       "6113": 0.109, "5115": 0.062, 
       "47077": 0.181,
}


yyy = {key: int(value) for key, value in xxx.items()}
# yyy = {key: 0 for key, value in xxx.items()}  # Si el valor siempre debe ser 0

print(yyy)
```

Daría como salida:

```
{'5113': 0, '6105': 0, '6107': 0, '6109': 0, '48213': 0, '6111': 0, '6113': 0, '5115': 0, '47077': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar la librería [tools](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz) que tiene justo lo que necesitas y mucho más de una manera mas legible.

```
import toolz
toolz.valmap(int, xxx)
```

Con esto haces un mapeo de la función int sobre los valores del diccionario.